# MySQL Joining 3 Quiz Tables with Calculated Totals By Attribute/User

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following tables which I am trying to combine into one query (with the ultimate goal being to output a CSV file from PHP):

**users**

```
id, name, email
```

eg. data

```
1, John, email@email.com
2, Jane, email@email.com
```

**questions** - a static list of questions, each question is of one of 3 types stored as "attribute," which is a single letter [A, B, C]

```
id, text, attribute
```

eg. data

```
1, How cool are dogs?, A
2, How cool are cats?, B
3, How cool are fish?, A
4, How cool are mice?, C
5, How cool are birds?, B
```

**users_questions** - where answer is an integer [1-5]

```
id, user_id, question_id, answer
```

eg. data

```
1, 1, 1, 2
2, 1, 2, 5
3, 1, 3, 1
4, 1, 4, 1
5, 1, 5, 4

6, 2, 1, 4
7, 2, 2, 1
8, 2, 3, 3
9, 2, 4, 2
10, 2, 5, 2
```

## Desired results:

I'm trying to combine all of this data as one query with the questions for each user totalled grouped by attribute so the output format is something like:

```
users.id, users.name, users.email    , A_question_total, B_question_total, C_question_total
       1, John      , email@email.com,                3,                9,                1
       2, Jane      , email@email.com,                7,                3,                2
```

## What I have currently:

I've tried the queries below which all give me almost what I need:

I'm able to select everything joined together, but this duplicates users and questions and doesn't give me the question totals by user/attribute:

```
Select * FROM users
JOIN users_questions ON users.id = users_questions.user_id
JOIN questions ON questions.id = users_questions.question_id;
```

I can also select all the question totals by user/attribute, but then I'd have to grab the users separately and then connect them together in PHP.

```
SELECT questions.attribute, users_questions.user_id, SUM(users_questions.answer) AS `total` FROM `questions` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users_questions` ON questions.id = users_questions.`question_id` GROUP BY users_questions.user_id, questions.attribute;
```

I'm wondering if there is a way with complex joining, grouping, subqueries, etc. to be able to do this all in one query. I'm struggling as to how to combine the above two queries and also convert what is essentially separate calculated total "rows" in columns for each user.

Here's the sql dump of the example data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `questions`;

CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute` enum('A','B','C') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `questions` (`id`, `text`, `attribute`)
VALUES
    (1,'How cool are dogs?','A'),
    (2,'How cool are cats?','B'),
    (3,'How cool are fish?','A'),
    (4,'How cool are mice?','C'),
    (5,'How cool are birds?','B');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`)
VALUES
    (1,'John','email@email.com'),
    (2,'Jane','email@email.com');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users_questions`;

CREATE TABLE `users_questions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users_questions` (`id`, `user_id`, `question_id`, `answer`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1,2),
    (2,1,2,5),
    (3,1,3,1),
    (4,1,4,1),
    (5,1,5,4),
    (6,2,1,4),
    (7,2,2,1),
    (8,2,3,3),
    (9,2,4,2),
    (10,2,5,2);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us what the desired result would actually look like?

Comment: Sure, it's in the question. I added some header formatting to clarify the desired results. Basically I'm trying to output a combined result that has user info, alongside totals for each question type so name, email, A_total, B_total, C_total, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1875f2/5)) will solve your problem:

```
Select u.id, u.name, u.email, 
SUM(case q.attribute when 'A' then uq.answer else 0 end) as A_question_total,
SUM(case q.attribute when 'B' then uq.answer else 0 end) as B_question_total,
SUM(case q.attribute when 'C' then uq.answer else 0 end) as C_question_total
FROM users u
JOIN users_questions uq ON u.id = uq.user_id
JOIN questions q ON q.id = uq.question_id
group by u.id
```

Output:

```
id  name    email               A_question_total    B_question_total    C_question_total
1   John    email@email.com     3                   9                   1
2   Jane    email@email.com     7                   3                   2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I'm looking for, but I'm trying to total the answer field not the number of questions. So if user # 1 answers 3 for the first A question and 2 for the second A question, then A_question_total would be 5 for that user and so on.

Comment: Actually, looking at your fiddle I can make it work by changing it slightly: `Select u.id, u.name, u.email, 
SUM(case q.attribute when 'A' then uq.answer else 0 end) as A_question_total,
SUM(case q.attribute when 'B' then uq.answer else 0 end) as B_question_total,
SUM(case q.attribute when 'C' then uq.answer else 0 end) as C_question_total
FROM users u
JOIN users_questions uq ON u.id = uq.user_id
JOIN questions q ON q.id = uq.question_id
group by u.id` That seems to work unless someone knows a more concise way to write the query.

Comment: Hi Kevin, obviously I slightly misinterpreted your question. I've updated the answer & fiddle to reflect that.